# Parallax not working when hosted

Tags: javascript, html, web, tags, parallax

header doesn't work at augiepark.com

Local preview works fine, but it's when the site is hosted when the parallax stops working.

Can any one help?

```
<div id="scene">
        <div class="layer" data-depth=".1">
          <div class="layer3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer" data-depth="0.3">
          <div class="layer1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer" data-depth="0.4">
          <div class="layer2"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scene').parallax();
});
```

In my portfolio, the js is located on line 535 but I'm not sure if that's the right area it should be in

Answer (score 0):

I see you call jquery library several times on that page. Can you try to remove some and put only one of these lines ?

```
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```